# Finding a basis for the physical constants?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, physics, machine-learning

I was not able to find much on this topic besides [this article](https://www.nature.com/news/2007/071220/full/news.2007.389.html), and don't know if this is even something worth considering, but it has been stuck with me for a while.

Since any given set of data is linearly separable in some dimension, could there be some basis where all physical constants (i.e. plancks constant, speed of light in a vacuum) could be represented as integers? If so, how would one go about tackling this problem (machine learning model?) and what applications would a good outcome have?

Comment: You can choose a system of units where all the fundamental constants take whatever value you want. See for example [Planck Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) for an example where $G =c=\hbar = 1$.

Comment: @Winther: That’s not correct. You can only choose a finite number of constants (7 if you stay within an SI-compatible system) to be 1. Also see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327246/36360) on Physics SE.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Well that is what is meant by "fundamental constants"